# Acesso negado ao acessar controller com CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Fiz uma aplicação com code igniter e implementei uma tela de login. Ao realizar o login, o usuário é direcionado à tela de dashboard. Ao clicar em qualquer link dessa tela, a mensagem de "Acesso proibido" é apresentada:

[image: Acesso proibido]

Fiz uma checagem para entender qual é a diferença entre a tela de login (que funciona) e as outras telas para entender o problema.

**Formulário de login:**

```
  <div class="container">
<div class="card card-login mx-auto mt-5">
  <div class="card-header">Finanças</div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <form role="form" method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('login/auth');?>">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="login">Login</label>
        <input class="form-control c-form-control" id="login" name="username" type="text" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Senha</label>
        <input class="form-control c-form-control" id="password" name="password" type="password">
      </div>
      <input type="submit" name="btnAcessar" value="Acessar" class="btn c-btn-login btn-block">
    </form>
    <div class="text-center">
      <a class="d-block c-a-style small mt-3" href="#">Esqueceu a senha?</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Método login/auth**

```
public function auth() {

    //Captura da requisição os dados que vieram do formulario
    $username = $this->input->post('username');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');

    // Captura os dados do banco e valida com os da requisição
    $userInfo = $this->user_model->get_user($username);

    if(strtolower($username) == strtolower($userInfo["USERNAME"]) && md5($password) == $userInfo["PASSWORD"]){

        $data['username'] = $userInfo["USERNAME"];
        $data['name'] = $userInfo["NAME"];

        $this->session->set_userdata("user_logged", $username);
        $this->load->view('templates/system-header', $data);
        $this->load->view('pages/Dashboard', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/system-footer');
    } else {
        echo "Usuário e/ou senha incorretos.";
    }
}
```

**Exemplo de chamada à qualquer tela dentro da aplicação**

```
<li class="nav-item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Titulos">
      <a class="nav-link call-content" href="<?php echo site_url('application/titulos');?>" value="pedidos">
        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-file-text-o"></i>
        <span class="nav-link-text">Titulos</span>
      </a>
    </li>
```

**metodo Application/titulos**

```
public function titulos($page = 'titulos') {
    if (!file_exists(APPPATH.'views/pages/'.$page.'.php')) {
        show_404();
    }
    $this->load->view('templates/system-header', $data);
    $this->load->view('pages/titulos', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/system-footer');
}
```

O próprio framework gerou um arquivo .htaccess na pasta 'views':

```
<IfModule authz_core_module>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
```

e tenho um arquivo .htaccess na raiz do projeto para 'ocultar' o index.php da url:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Acho importante dizer que estou usando session. Como a tela de erro não está formatada como o CodeIgniter faz, acredito ser algo com o PHP ou o XAMPP que estou usando. Os diretórios tem acesso full à leitura e gravação. Estou usando localmente no meu Windows 10.

Alguma ideia do que pode ser?

Comment: Você usa algum arquivo .htacess no projeto?

Comment: @rray uso sim, vou adicionar à pergunta.

Comment: Isso me parece erro de usúario  ou permissão na pasta do domínio dentro de /home em seu servidor. Geralmente a permissão para o apache é 0755 dá uma conferida nas permissões de arquivos e posta ai.

Comment: Olha o erro no servidor tem que olhar principalmente essas pastas. 
application system index.php

Comment: tem que estar 644

Comment: Depende se o usuário do apache 0644 se estiver sobre o usuário do domínio 0755.Esse erro ai não é do php é do apache httpd status 403 é quando não há permissão de acesso ao arquivo.

Comment: No servidor funcionou bem. Uso um Ubuntu 16.04 na DigitalOcean. As permissões estão setadas como 0755. Localmente no Windows não funciona. O problema está nas permissões do apache, php ou no Xampp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro estava no arquivo config.php, localizado em `application/config/config.php`. a variavel `$config['index_page']` estava vazia. Adicionei o código abaixo e o problema foi solucionado:

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

O .htaccess não está ocultando o 'index.php' da url, mas isso é um problema para uma outra pergunta.